# How to add a column with the growth rate in a budget table in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I would like to know how can I add a growth rate year to year in the following data in Pandas.

```
    Date  Total Managed Expenditure
0   2001                      503.2
1   2002                      529.9
2   2003                      559.8
3   2004                      593.2
4   2005                      629.5
5   2006                      652.1
6   2007                      664.3
7   2008                      688.2
8   2009                      732.0
9   2010                      759.2
10  2011                      769.2
11  2012                      759.8
12  2013                      760.6
13  2014                      753.3
14  2015                      757.6
15  2016                      753.9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Series[.pct_change()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html):

```
df['Total Managed Expenditure'].pct_change()
Out: 
0          NaN
1     0.053060
2     0.056426
3     0.059664
4     0.061194
5     0.035902
6     0.018709
7     0.035978
8     0.063644
9     0.037158
10    0.013172
11   -0.012220
12    0.001053
13   -0.009598
14    0.005708
15   -0.004884
Name: Total Managed Expenditure, dtype: float64
```

To assign it back:

```
df['Growth Rate'] = df['Total Managed Expenditure'].pct_change()
```

Comment: Do you know how to make it just two decimal places?

Comment: You can add `.round(2)` at the end: `df['Total Managed Expenditure'].pct_change().round(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to obtain a cutom metric using previous cells' values uses .shift(n) method. (in my case I needed ln(x1/x0) ):

```
df['ln_rate'] = np.log(df.value/df.value.shift(1))
```

of for your % change.

```
df['percent_change'] = (df.value/df.value.shift(1))-1
```

shift(n) moves the values up or down 'n' rows, replacing the bottom or upper rows with NaN values.